# How to store time as a variable and subtract from current time in R?

Tags: python, r, logging, time, system

I want to log the time in `R` like I do in `Python 3` but I have no idea where to even start.  In `Python` I would do it this way.  How would I do this same thing in `R`?

```
>>> import time
>>> start_time = time.time()
>>> time.time() - start_time
6.0202391147613525
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sys.time` is what you need.

```
current_time <- Sys.time()
Sys.time() - current_time

#Time difference of 2.900852 secs
```

However, this has a class of `difftime`

```
class(Sys.time() - current_time)
#[1] "difftime"
```

If you want it as a number for manipulation you can use `as.numeric`

```
as.numeric(Sys.time() - current_time)
#[1] 2.900852
```

The units are not always constant here and you might face issues handling it. So for example, when I now do

```
Sys.time() - current_time
```

it gives me

```
#Time difference of 12.12814 mins
```

Point here to observe is at first the units were in seconds and now they are in minutes. So this is inconsistent and maybe troublesome when you are using them for some calculation.

To overcome that , as @r2evans mentions in the comment we can set the units by doing

```
my_diff = Sys.time() - current_time
units(my_diff) <- "secs"

my_diff
#Time difference of 592.8649 secs
```

So this would always return difference in seconds irrespective of the duration passed.

Comment: It's important to mention that the units are not always convenient, and cannot be explicitly set using the simple subtraction operator. To override the units: `units(mydiff) <- "mins"`, where more help can be found in [`?units`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/difftime.html).

Comment: How can I convert to a string so it says "Time difference of 2.900852 secs" if I do `write(x, stdout())`

Comment: @O.rka something like `paste("Time difference of ",my_diff, "seconds")` ?

Comment: (Thank you for not suggesting `capture.output(...)` :-)

Comment: Ok yea that works.  I didn't know if there was a function I could throw it in that would capture the output directly.  Like `str` or `repr` in `Python`

Answer (score 0):

Use `proc.time()` like this:

```
start_time <- proc.time()
Sys.sleep(1)
proc.time() - start_time
```

giving:

```
user  system elapsed 
0.00    0.03    1.04
```

To time an expression:

```
system.time(Sys.sleep(1))
```

giving:

```
user  system elapsed 
   0       0       1
```

Also see the microbenchmark, rbenchmark and tictoc packages.